# Questions about database in linux without mysql

Tags: linux, database, bash, scripting

I'm trying to make a database in linux , so I try to modify columns and records in file but I can not make it well 
so I'm asking how to
1st question :
 1-delete  2-edit a column like ID or name

2nd question 
 how to deal with records ,1- how to delete specific record (complete row)   2- select a certain value and edit it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of data do you want to store?

Comment: Integers and strings 
ID int
Name string 
.. 
etc

Comment: I see. Why not use SQLite?

Comment: it is project after course and they need it with simple commands like cut - grep - sed - awk ..... etc

Comment: Okay. Please edit the question to include your records file and the record manipulation code you've written so far to. It's hard to answer your questions without them.

Comment: I have already wrote this 1-delete 2-edit a column like ID or name